# How can I view the source code of a base function in R?

Tags: r

I want to see the source code for `list.files()` because I want to add a progress bar to the function. The solutions for this in the stackoverflow post below don't work for viewing the source code of `list.files()` and I don't understand why.

[How can I view the source code for a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function)

Comment: Try `getAnywhere(list.files)`?